# How to remove / update registration from Autofac for a extensible application with add-on?

Tags: autofac

I'm building a web application which allow users to upload extensions to extend it. An extension is a zip which contains assemblies. I have no problem loading the assembly inside the AppDomain and I know that there is no way to remove assemblies from AppDomain..

The user should be able to disable or upgrade extension.

I use Autofac.

After upgrading an extension, I use this kind of code :

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(v2assembly);
builder.Update(container);
```

Where `v2assembly` is the new assembly which contains a module which only overrides the Load method to register its services.

My problem is that after upgrading an extension, when I resolve `IEnumerable<IService>` the container returns 2 services : one from *v1* assembly and another one from *v2* assembly.

Unfortunately, I have some requirements :

- My application can use instance (not coming from any extension) resolved by the container in another thread that take times, for example, a database import operation.  Upgrading an extension should not break this long running operation;
- My application uses singleton instances which take times to initialize and an extension upgrade should not reset this singleton for performance reasons;
- Instances that should be *replaced* may implements IDisposable and should be disposed during the upgrade process;
- When an extension is disabled the *runtime* implementation should be used when I resolve a specific type.

Do you have ideas to resolve this problem ?

One of my idea is to register type coming from extension using a metadata which will indicates the version of the extension then implements an IRegistrationSource which will use an instance that is not coming from a disabled extension.
I don't know how exactly to do this, and what will be the impact of such a registrationsource.

Answer (score 3):

The answer most likely involves registering your new components in a new `LifetimeScope`, and disposing a previous one. I wouldn't update the existing scope, because then the original singletons will continue to live on.